# Link php container with mongodb container

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, docker, ubuntu

I am new in Docker and Mongodb. I have a mongodb container with a database and collection. I created another container with php and apache using following command:

```
docker run -d -p 8020:80 --name my-php-apache php:7-apache
```

In order to be able to connect to mongodb container (my-mongo), i need to link this container to mongodb container. So i used following command to link both containers:

```
docker run -d -p 8020:80 --link my-mongo --name php-mongo-link php:7-apache
```

But it shows following error:

```
b36e400bb5c0d229f952a7b365d5a8bfed402410bdb5a802f29fd2fdc1ef28f9

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint php-mongo-link (ec4eb66d0a314201c99f79eb4a09cf82ffb2fc399647020adaf34932878857b7): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8020 failed: port is already allocated.
```

To link the containers, should the ports of php-apache (8020:80) and php-mongo-link be same ? Or should they be different ? Is there any better way to link 2 containers (php-apache and mongodb) ? I just need to connect from the php container to the mongodb container to insert some data in the mongodb database.

Comment: What's the difference between the `my-php-apache` and the `php-mongo-link` container; they both seem to be running the same image?  [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) in the Docker documentation is probably what you're looking for, though it's not the most approachable explanation.

Comment: @DavidMaze my-php-apache is the name of php:7-apache container and php-mongo-link is the link connecting mongodb container with php-apache container. let me know if you have any better idea to connect the two containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `docker run --link` at all on modern Docker.  You need to [create a Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) (default settings are just fine) and then run both containers attached to that network.  The containers will be able to reach each other using the `--name` of the container as a host name.

```sh
docker network create myapp
docker run \
  -d \                 # in the background
  --net myapp \        # attached to the network
  -v ... \             # with persistent storage
  --name my-mongodb \
  mongo:4.2
docker run \
  -d \                 # in the background
  --net myapp \        # attached to the network
  -p 8020:80 \         # accessible from outside
  --name my-php-apache \
  -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://my-mongodb:27017 \
  php:7-apache
```

(If you use Docker Compose, [it does this setup automatically](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).)

Every time you `docker run` something it creates a new container.  A link is a property of a container that allows it to connect to a specific other container, in the networking model that existed before Docker 1.0; you need to specify it when you start the first container.  In your example you're running a container, then running a second copy of it with the link setting; you're getting a conflict because both containers publish the same host port (`-p 8020:...`).  If you were to use `--link` it would be on the first `docker run` command, and you wouldn't need a second one.

Comment: i used bridge network, but still unable to connect with mongodb container from php container

Comment: from my php container, i am running a php script to connect with mondb container like : $mongoClient = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://my-mongo:27017');   But, var_dump($mongoClient) shows following- object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(24) "mongodb://my-mongo:27017" ["cluster"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: does it mean it's connected with mongodb ?

Comment: can you have a look at this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685240/insert-data-into-mongodb-database-from-php7-apache-container

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you expose both container on the same port `8020` , so one must listen on `8021` .

extract from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

> Publish or expose port (-p, --expose)
>
> $ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash
>
> This binds port 8080 of the container to TCP port 80 on 127.0.0.1 of
>   the host machine. You can also specify udp and sctp ports. The Docker
>   User Guide explains in detail how to manipulate ports in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

You hand bind both containers to the same port on your host maschine. Both are bind to port 80. You should use another port for the second container like 81.

```
docker run -d -p 8020:81 --link my-mongo --name php-mongo-link php:7-apache
```